# how can I get JSON from HTTP request as a String and not as JsValue

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am playing around with Json object. Is there a way to get the Json passed in HTTP request as String and not as JsValue? I want to use Json object to parse it instead of using asJson.

```
def registrationRequest = Action { request => {
    Logger.debug("received message:"+request)
    Logger.debug("received message:"+request.body)
    val jsv:JsValue = Json.parse**(/* I want to get json as string here from request's body*/)**
    (jsv \ "first-name").asOpt[String].map(nameValue=>{
        Logger.debug("name is "+nameValue); Ok(nameValue)
      }).getOrElse{BadRequest("no name")}
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get raw text from JSON request by using `tolerantText` parser:

```
def index = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
    val jsonAsString = request.body
}
```